# Working with Akka AbstractActorWithTimers from Java API

Tags: java, groovy, akka

I'm trying to use the new Akka Timers API inside a Java (well, Groovy, really) app, of course using the Akka/Java API (Gradle coordinates I'm using are `'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.5.4'`). When I try to create my new timer-laced actor, I get compiler errors:

```
class MyTimeAwareActor extends AbstractActorWithTimers {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message in StartNewTimer) {
            timers.startPeriodicTimer(/* blah whatever */)
        }
    }
}
```

This code yields a compiler error on my use of the `@Override` annotation:

> "*Groovy:Method 'onReceive' from class `com.example.myapp.MyTimeAwareActor` does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override.*"

This tells me I'm using this actor incorrectly. All I want to do is start a new timer (that does something) every time the actor receives a `StartNewTimer` message.

Any ideas how I can do that and fix this compiler error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `onReceive` with `createReceive` (the following is in Java; you can convert it to Groovy):

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .match(StartNewTimer.class, message -> {
            getTimers().startPeriodicTimer(/* blah whatever */);
        })
        .build();
}
```

`onReceive` is not defined in `AbstractActorWithTimers` or its parent, `AbstractActor` (`onReceive` is defined in `UntypedAbstractActor`).

Comment: Thanks @chunjef (+1) I'll give it a try here in a little bit. Curious: is this the "new proper way" to define actors (via `createReceive` instead of `onReceive`)? If so, any idea why I don't get this error in my actor classes that just extend `UntypedActor`? Thanks again!

Comment: Also I haven't forgotten about your excellent answer to my Akka/Timer question from last week -- I need to get this working before I can test out your previous suggestions, but once I get everything working you get the green check for both questions!

Comment: @smeeb: Yes, use `AbstractActor` or classes that extend it (such as `AbstractActorWithTimers`) and implement `createReceive`. You don't get the same error with actors that extend `UntypedActor`, because `UntypedActor` does have an `onReceive` method. Don't use `UntypedActor`; it is deprecated, as mentioned [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html#untypedactor). (`UntypedAbstractActor` is a migration bridge between `UntypedActor` and `AbstractActor`.)